# Intervalos de crescimento dos valores de um array

Tags: c#, .net, array

Gostaria de saber uma maneira de determinar os **intervalos de crescimento e decrescimento de um vetor** em *C#*.

Exemplo:

> Array[0]=0; Array[1]=1; Array[2]=2;
>
> Array[3]=3; Array[4]=4; Array[5]=3;
>
> Array[6]=2; Array[7]=1; Array[8]=0;
>
> Array[9]=1; Array[10]=2;

**Intervalos de crescimento: 0-4, 8-10**

**Intervalos de decrescimento: 4-8**

EDIT:

> Da posição 0 a 4 e da posição 8 a 10 do vetor exemplo os valores estão crescendo e da posição 4 a 8 o valores estão diminuindo.

Comment: Não consegui entender sua pergunta. Poderia me explicar por favor? :/

Comment: vou editar aqui amigo

Comment: Você quer gerar números aleatórios para inserir no array, porém quando for índice 0 a 4 ou 8 a 10 tem que ser em ordem crescente, mas quando for do índice 4 a 8 precisa inserir na ordem decrescente?

Comment: não, eu ja tenho o vetor com as posições preenchidas, quero encontrar os intervalos onde os valores estão subindo ou descendo.

Comment: Montei um código do tipo CONSOLE Application rapidão, vou disponibilizar para ter uma idéia do que você deseja... vamos ver se os administradores daqui não ficam bravos comigo... eu quero ganhar pontos aqui, mas o pessoal do JAVA não deixa... KKKKK!

Comment: E qual é o critério?

Comment: Da posição 5 até a posição 8 está decrescente...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece estar ok:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Interval
    {
        public int Min { get; set; }
        public int Max { get; set; }

        public Interval(List<int> list, int current)
        {
            list.Add(current);

            this.Min = list.Min();
            this.Max = list.Max();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}-{1}", Min, Max);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {        
        static void Main()
        {
            var intArr = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2 };

            var listAux = new List<int>();

            bool? isCres = null;

            var intervalCres = new List<Interval>();
            var intervalDecres = new List<Interval>();

            for (int i = 0; i < intArr.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (intArr[i] < intArr[i + 1])
                {
                    if (isCres == false)
                    {
                        intervalDecres.Add(new Interval(listAux, i));
                        listAux.Clear();
                    }
                    isCres = true;
                    listAux.Add(i);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (isCres == true)
                    {
                        intervalCres.Add(new Interval(listAux, i));
                        listAux.Clear();
                    }
                    isCres = false;
                    listAux.Add(i);
                }
            }

            if ((bool)isCres) intervalCres.Add(new Interval(listAux, intArr.Length - 1));
            else intervalDecres.Add(new Interval(listAux, intArr.Length - 1));

            Console.WriteLine("Crescimento:");
            intervalCres.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

            Console.WriteLine("\nDecrescimento:");
            intervalDecres.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> Crescimento: 0-4  8-10
>
> Decrescimento: 4-8

Answer (score 2):

Exemplo de código:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] intNum = new int[11];

        intNum[0] = 0;
        intNum[1] = 1;
        intNum[2] = 2;
        intNum[3] = 3;
        intNum[4] = 4;
        intNum[5] = 3;
        intNum[6] = 2;
        intNum[7] = 1;
        intNum[8] = 0;
        intNum[9] = 1;
        intNum[10] = 2;

        for (int i = 1; i < intNum.Length; i++)
        {
            if (intNum[i - 1] < intNum[i])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cresceu");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Decresceu");
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Veja também no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/s08Lvf).

O exemplo abaixo mostra os índices de início e fim de cada intervalo e o sinal da derivada primeira (+1 se for positiva, 0 se for constante e -1, se negativa).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2 };

        Console.WriteLine("arr");
        foreach (var intervalo in arr.IntervalosCrescimento())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Start {intervalo.Item1}, end {intervalo.Item2}, sinal {intervalo.Item3}");
        }

        int[] arr2 = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, -1, -8, 0, 8 };

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("arr2");
        foreach (var intervalo in arr2.IntervalosCrescimento())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Start {intervalo.Item1}, end {intervalo.Item2}, sinal {intervalo.Item3}");
        }
    }
}

public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int, int>> IntervalosCrescimento<T>(this IEnumerable<T> en) where T : IComparable
    {
        bool first = true;

        Tuple<int, int, int> result;

        int start = 0, end = 0;

        T previous = default(T);

        int? previousSign = null;
        int? sign = null;

        int index = 0;

        foreach (T current in en)
        {
            if (first)
            {
                first = false;
                start = index;
                previous = current;
            }
            else
            {
                sign = current.CompareTo(previous);

                if (previousSign == null)
                {
                    previousSign = sign;
                }
                else if (previousSign != sign)
                {
                    end = index;

                    result = Tuple.Create(start, end, previousSign.Value);

                    start = index;
                    previousSign = sign;

                    yield return result;
                }

                previous = current;
                ++index;
            }
        }

        end = index;

        if (start < end)
            yield return Tuple.Create(start, end, sign.Value);
    }
}
```